# Must the radical of polynomial evaluated at integers be small enough at least once?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Basically I am interested if the radical of polynomial evaluated at integers can be small enough at least once.

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x], \deg(f)>1$ be squarefree. For integer $a$ and $f(a) \ne 0$ 
in analogy with the $abc$ conjecture define the quality of $f(a)$:
$$ q_1(f(a)) = \frac{\log(|a|^{\deg(f)-1})}{\log(rad(f(a)))}$$

> Q1 Is there a positive constant $C$ such that for all $f$ exists $a$ such that $q_1(f(a)) > 1 + C$?

$abc$ implies this is possible at most finitely often for fixed $C$.

For infinitely many $f$, $C$ can be arbitrary large - make $f(a)=2^n$ by
adjusting the free coefficient.

Closely related:

Let $F \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y],\deg(F)>2$ be squarefree and homogeneous.

Define the quality of nonzero $F(a,b)$ for $a,b$ integers:

$$ q_2(F(a,b)) = \frac{\log(\max(|a|,|b|)^{\deg(F)-2})}{\log(rad(F(a,b)))}$$

> Q2 Is there a positive constant $C$ such that for all $F$ exist coprime $a,b$ such that $q_2(F(a,b)) > 1 + C$?

If the general answer is hard, make some restrictions on $f,F$
(maybe require real irrational root).

Comment: I mean positive **real** $C$.

Comment: Since you're presumably not asking us to prove the $abc$ conjecture, I'm interpreting your question as this: for all $C>0$, construct a polynomial $f$ (depending on $C$) such that $q_1(f(a)) \le 1+C$ for every integer $a$ (with $f(a)\ne0$). Is that accurate? If so, you could edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @GregMartin I definitely don't want proof of abc. abc wants finitely many solutions for all $f,C$. As explained in the question, for arbitrary large $C$, exists $f$ with at least one $a$ (this is one solution). Your suggestion for constructing polynomial $f$ s.t. $q_1(f(a)) < 1+C$ will be an answer modulo that I allow restrictions on $f,F$ for positive answer. Maybe will edit later, feel free to answer if you can.

Comment: @GregMartin Observe that by congruence reasons, $f(a)$ will be divisible by squares or higher powers of primes infinitely often, so this might affect the value of $C$ unless $\log()$ takes care of this.

Comment: It's true that I don't see a direct connection between Q1 and the $abc$ conjecture. Q2 is certainly a generalization though, thanks to $F(a,b) = ab(a+b)$.

Comment: @GregMartin answer to $ab(a+b)$ will give you _one_ good triple which certainly exists. I am asking for _once_. Am I missing something?